# What logic behind rspec-rails generates non-REST description like `POST /create`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request, rspec-rails, scaffolding

[rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) provides scaffold generators for [request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/6-0/docs/request-specs). It [generates](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/main/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/templates/request_spec.rb#L65) following code:

```rb
RSpec.describe "/widgets", type: :request do
  # ...
  describe "POST /create" do
    context "with valid parameters" do
      it "creates a new Widget" do
        expect {
          post widgets_url, params: { widget: valid_attributes }
```

`rspec -f d` output is following

```
/widgets
  POST /create
    with valid parameters
      creates a new Widget
```

So such route as `POST /widgets/create` actually doesn't exist whereas `POST /widgets` exists.

What is the scheme behind this kind of description? Is there formal definition of this approach?

P.S. Only explanation I can provide is that scheme is `Model —> HTTP verb —> /CRUD action` but it seems to have not much sense.

Comment: Your question is based on your opinion and thus is likely to lead to opinion based answers. That being said have you actually looked at how this is "documented" when you use the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-12/docs/command-line/format-option#documentation-format) format? It might make a lot more sense if you look at it that way?

Answer (score 0):

```
So here the type of RSpec test is request so 
  post => http verb
  widgets_url => is request_path or request_url of create method
  params => you pass attributes for post http method

If you use type of RSpec is controller then you have to write this
 You need to use method name instead of request_path or request_url

  RSpec.describe WidgetsController, type: :controller do
    describe "POST #create " do
     context "with valid parameters" do
      it "creates a new Widget" do
        expect {
          post :create, params: { widget: valid_attributes }
        }.to eq("") 
      end
     end
    end
  end
```